# Regex one or two digit nubers sequences in input.val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check an input value to match one or two digit numbers separated by spaces. No alphanumeric characters only numbers and spaces. The correct string looks like this:

```
1 3 12 34 55 67 3
```

It can contain one number or multiple one or two digit numbers separated by space. How can I check with regex this string to be valid?

This is what I did so far :

```
\d{1,2}\s.test(the_string)
```

Thank you!

Comment: With `/^\d{1,2}(?:\s\d{1,2})*$/`, or something similar depending on the actual requirements.

Comment: It is not the exact duplicate, it is different by the lenght of the digits and the separator (only spaces and only 2 digit nubers). It is similar, that's true.

Comment: Believe me, it is. Once I answered almost an identical question, and got 6 downvotes, the question got closed as a dupe of like 6 other posts and the duplicate was just like I used here. Just different in a quantifier.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway for pointing me to the right direction and providing the answer ! Do you realy need the to down vote ?

Comment: I did not downvote, I ran out of votes a couple of hours ago.

Comment: If I delete the question your useful question votes will be removed to ?

Comment: You do not have to delete it.